# SmartTarget content being deployed using .Net server tag: <smarttarget:ComponentPresentation ... />

Tags: content-delivery, smarttarget

I've just installed the content deployer portion of the SmartTarget 2013 installation and found that my content is being deployed with the incorrect `.net` user control tag:

```
<smarttarget:ComponentPresentation ...  />
```

instead of

```
<tridion:ComponentPresentation ... />
```

Having checked the output of the `.aspx` file this is happening during the tcdl resolving stage of deployment and definitely not something incorrectly output from the result of modular templating.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem can be resolved by simply checking the cd_deployer_conf.xml file within the deploying application, the incorrect property

```
<TCDLEngine> 
<Properties> 
  <property Name="aspnet.tagprefix" Value="smarttarget" />
```

Should become:

```
<TCDLEngine> 
<Properties> 
  <property Name="aspnet.tagprefix" Value="tridion" />
```

**Note:** The incorrect `Value` attribute of "`smarttarget`"

Once you've saved the file, restart the deployer application and republish a page to check the correct output is produced.

Thanks to Nuno Linhares for the help resolving this one :)